# SQLAlchemy, one to many list always drop to one object after a commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is how I have defined my basket, with a to many 'items' relationships:

```
class Basket(Base):
 __tablename__ = 'basket'
 id             = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
 items_id       = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'))
 items          = relationship("Item", uselist=True)

class Item(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'item'
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String)
```

But when I test it, for some raison, after a session commit, my basket.items only keep one item. If I add some more, then commit again, my list will stay at one.

I don't understand why. Here is my test:

```
>>> basket = Basket()
>>> s = session()
>>> s.add(basket)
>>> banana = Item(name="banana")
>>> orange = Item(name="orange") 
>>> s.add(banana)
>>> s.add(orange)
>>> s.commit()
>>> basket.items.append(banana)
>>> basket.items.append(orange)
>>> basket.items
[<database.declarative.Item object at 0x10e4c7790>, <database.declarative.Item object at 0x10e4c7810>]
>>> s.commit()
>>> basket.items
[<database.declarative.Item object at 0x10e4c7810>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration specifies a many-to-one relationship from `Basket` to `Item`, because it uses the foreign key `Basket.item_id`. You can only ever have one id on that column, so you'll only ever be able to have one `Item` in `Basket.items`, even if you specify `uselist=True`.

The correct way to model this is to place the foreign key on `Item` instead:

```
class Basket(Base):
    ...
    items          = relationship("Item")

class Item(Base):
    ...
    basket_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Basket.id))
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Now you said it, it seems obvious. My error was to think that the control layer was working be on the class side, and never let add more than one item at a time into the items list, like throwing an exception if that case happen. So the changes and correction are performed when the commit is done. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score -1):

s.commit() may be releasing the entire session. You'll want to flush, then finally commit at the end.

```
s.flush()
```